# Can JSON be edited using JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

For example I have a JSON data like

```
olddata = {
    userNname : "joeydash",
    sex : "female",
    email : "ae16b001@smail.iitm.ac.in"
};
dataToEdit = {
    name = "Mritunjoy Das",
    sex = "male"
};
```

Is there any function in javascript such that if i do

```
newData = doSomething(oldData,dataToEdit);
console.log(newData);
```

it shows

```
{
   userNname : "joeydash",
   name : "Mritunjoy Das"
   sex : "male",
   email : "ae16b001@smail.iitm.ac.in"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
olddata = {
    userNname : "joeydash",
    sex : "female",
    email : "ae16b001@smail.iitm.ac.in"
};
dataToEdit = {
    name : "Mritunjoy Das",
    sex : "male"
};
var newData = Object.assign(olddata, dataToEdit);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: If you want to have a new object, created from `olddata`, you should use `newData=Object.assign({},olddata,dataToEdit)` instead. But even so, keep in mind that this will not be a "deep" copy.

Comment: You're right, but the author didn't asked for a deep copy

Comment: Pretty sure the author didn't ask for `olddata` to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function doSomething(oldData,dataToEdit){
     for (var key in dataToEdit) {
         if (dataToEdit.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              oldData[key] = dataToEdit[key];       
         }
     }
     return oldData;
}
```

Also change `=` to `:` as:

```
dataToEdit = {
    name : "Mritunjoy Das",
    sex : "male"
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much